# How to use Unicode characters with Sphinx rst documents and properly generate PDF files?

Tags: pdftex, unicode, sphinx

I discovered that if I use some Unicode characters inside `.rst` files, I will loose them when I convert the documentation to pdf using Sphinx.

Example chars: "șț".

When I run `make latexpdf` I get a document without these Unicode characters.

Comment: An option (which I used) is to run `xelatex` on file produced by Sphinx, though you have to adjust preamble in the config file.

Answer (score 7):

Currently You can use xelatex manually for that. Add

```
latex_elements = {
    'inputenc': '',
    'utf8extra': '',
    'preamble': '''

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setromanfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
''',
}
```

to conf.py, make latex code, and run the xelatex manually:

```
sphinx-build -b latex -d _build/doctrees . _build/xetex && cd _build/xetex; xelatex *.tex
```

Comment: You might want to use r''' ''' around the preamble. Or Double the \\'s to properly escape them.

Comment: for passers-by: answer of @czam points out `latex_engine` configuration variable which did not exist at time of @Adobe answering, so now `make latexpdf` will use `xelatex` out of the box with `latex_engine = 'xelatex'`.

Answer (score 7):

Also consider using XeLaTeX, it can be configured as LaTeX engine in conf.py.

From the [Sphinx documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/latex.html):

```
# inside conf.py
latex_engine = 'xelatex'
```

Comment: sorry that you got downvoted, downvoting seems to become a plague of tex.sx these days (I wish I could downvote the downvoter, because downvoting this was pretty stupid, I have to say)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about Sphinx, but the problem seems to be in the fact that the option `utf8` to `inputenc` doesn't know about the comma below used in Romanian.

You can solve the problem by using the `utf8x` option or adding to the preamble for LaTeX compilation the following incantation

```
\makeatletter
\ProvideTextCommandDefault\textcommabelow[1]
  {\hmode@bgroup\ooalign{\null#1\crcr\hidewidth\raise-.31ex
   \hbox{\check@mathfonts\fontsize\ssf@size\z@
   \math@fontsfalse\selectfont,}\hidewidth}\egroup}
\makeatother
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{Ș}{\textcommabelow S}
\newunicodechar{ș}{\textcommabelow s}
\newunicodechar{Ț}{\textcommabelow T}
\newunicodechar{ț}{\textcommabelow t}
```

The code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` is from `uni-global.def` of the **ucs** package.

### Additional comments

Note that you need nothing special since the 2015 release of LaTeX has added support of all Romanian letters within `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, so `utf8x` is not needed any more, nor the explicit definitions with `\newunicodechar`.